# ReactJs - Selecting dynamic checkbox with coma separated value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make the multiple dynamic buttons selected from the string but it is not working with the comma-separated string.

**My code**

```
{thisLabels && thisLabels.map((names, index) => (
    <button type="button" className={`btn btn-outline-primary ${urltype === names ? "active" : ""}`} data-bs-toggle="button" autoComplete="off" name={names}>
        {names}
    </button>
))}
```

// "thisLabels" prints ["apple","grapes","banana","orange"]

**Works**

It works for the single button if urlType is a single string (non comma-separated) for example "apple"

**Doesn't work**

It doesn't work if urlType has a comma-separated string for example "apple,banana,orange,etc"

**Expected Result**

If the urlType has the following values "apple, banana, orange" then

button-apple (active)

button-grapes (no active)

button-banana (active)

button-orange (active)

Comment: Hot tip: make `thisLabels` always an array (never null or undefined) and remove `thisLabels &&`.

Comment: could you show what `thisLabels` actually looks like so I can test it on my own?

Comment: You should tokenize `urlType`. "Tokenize" is a fancy programming word which basically means split it up into an array. `const types = urlType.split(/, */);` then `${ types.includes('apple') ? 'active' : ''}`

Comment: @PRSHL I have added the output of the urlType